# Minimum value of slope if area under curve is given

Tags: calculus

If we have a function $f(x)$ and we are given the area under the curve, or rather say $\int_{a}^{b} f(x)dx = A$ then  is it possible to calculate the minimum possible absolute value of "|$max(slope)|$" in the graph of "$f(x)$ vs $x$" or in other words the minimum value of $|max(f'(x))|$ possible in the range $x \in(a,b)$?

I couldn't mathematically prove anything I felt or thought. Please let me know what you think, Thanks for your time.

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention the condition. The condition was that $f(b) = f(a) = 0$ basically that the values of  $f(b)$ and $f(a)$ are specified.

**EDIT[2]**: Note that $f$ should be continuous over $[a,b]$

Comment: My bad! Please check the edit

Comment: If we consider a triangle with top in the middle then any curve starting with a slope less should then grow faster to recover the area ? I think you should add absolute value of the slope else the case would have been a triangle until b and then a sudden descent. However I have no idea how to solve formally.

Comment: Specifying $f(b)$ and $f(a)$ doesn't change the fact that you can choose $f(x) = A/(b-a)$ constant in the $(a,b)$ interval. For the boundary conditions to have any effect, you need to require $f$ *continuous* over $[a,b]$.

Comment: @user3733558 I'll add it so in the question. I see that the question wouldn't make sense if it were not continuous.

Comment: Did you ask this for solving that rectilinear motion question from IITJEE 1993 where we had to find the maximum/minimum value of instantaneous acceleration? If that's the case, I'd recommend you to post the exact question because it will automatically take care of many conditions like continuity, values of $f(a)$ and $f(b)$, etc.

Comment: @Cretin2 That's exactly what I thought aswell but can't prove it. I'll add the condition for absolute too. btw wouldn't the function anyways be non differentiable at the tip of the triangle ?

Comment: @AnkitSaha Yeah I got that doubt from there. Although that question has other ways to solve this is what came across my mind first. The problem is that in that question we have equations of motion which would give us what the function $f$ is. I want to know if without knowing that function is we could find such a value

Comment: If you are indeed referring to that question, I don't think you have worded your question properly. In that question, you had to prove that the acceleration (slope) will exceed $4 ~\mathrm{ms^{-2}}$ at at least one point between $t= 0$ and $ 1$. But that is not the "minimum" acceleration (slope). This is why I recommended you to post the exact question. You can also request a mathematical-based approach in the same post along with the approaches you already know of.

Comment: @AnkitSaha I did not ask the minimum acceleration. I asked the minimum possible value of max(f'(x)), Which would imply for the condition $acc = 4$ in regards to that question. Like for all possible values of f'(x) atleast one should be >= y, would imply that if the minimum possible value of max(f'(x)) >= y in the graph then we could prove the same.

Comment: Also I think it would be an interesting question with regards to calculus. I believe that the triangle theory is probably correct  logically but idk how to prove it mathematically.

Comment: @Cretin2 What do you mean by the $C^\infty$ condition ?

Comment: $C^\infty$ are analytic functions, all their derivatives exist and are continuous

Answer (score 0):

Just knowing the area under the curve doesn't put any restrictions on the slope of the graph: it can be as large as you want, or it can be $0$. See if you can find a formula given $A$ and $m$ for a line with slope $m$ whose area under the curve is $A$.

Comment: Sorry, Please check the edit!